# Select/Delete iCloud Photos by phone uploaded from

Tags: icloud, photos, apple-id

Borrowed a phone from family member for a week, just switched the signed in account instead of resetting the phone.

But now all the photos on the old phone are mixed into my regular iCloud photos.
How can I delete the photos that were uploaded from this old phone?

Comment: Basically, it's a manual task - they're now all 'your' photos, same as all the others.

Answer (score -2):

Go to icloud.com

Enter the user ID and password

Scroll down, you will get the photos application Click on it. After that select the uploaded photos from your old phones and delete them, again you can delete them in recently deleted folder you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks i can do that on the phone also, I'm looking for a filter of some sort.

Comment: try sorting by date filter